# Regex to match "True" or "False"

Tags: asp.net, regex, vb.net, validation

I need to create Regular Expression validator which will need to match a text "True" or "False" (Case Insensitive).

I have tried the following regex

```
^(True|False|TRUE|FALSE)$
```

Is this correct? but there is problem in Case Sensitive.

**Edit**

I have tried regex in following answers but it's not firing, because of `?i`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have checked all the answers in this post but nothing worked as expected.

I Guess `?i` is not supported in Asp.Net RegularExpression validator.

Finally I used following regex.

```
^([Tt][Rr][Uu][Ee]|[Ff][Aa][Ll][Ss][Ee])$
```

It worked as expected.

This regex will be used for dynamically created Asp.net `RegularExpressionvalidator`.

Comment: It's not a good idea to tag the question with vb.net, while in fact you use javascript (client-side validation).

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov It's not javascript (client-side validation) .This regex will be used for dynamically created Asp.net RegularExpressionvalidator

Comment: It is javascript in the end. You can try answers above with `EnableClientScript` set to false and they will work.

Comment: What exactly didn't work? It will be triggered when you try to POST.

Comment: In the absence of `(?i)` I think this is one work around you can use.

Comment: You should've explained in the question that you'll be using asp.net's regularexpressionvalidator

Comment: @VigneshKumar, no I didn't do it. My answer was downvoted twice, that's why I commented that

Answer (score 14):

Either use `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`

or the inline `?i` modifier

```
^(?i)(true|false)$
```

Comment: Validation not firing with this expression because of `?i`

Answer (score 6):

With a small optimization:

```
^(?:tru|fals)e$
```

Since (?i) is not validating, we'll set the case insensitivity in the code.

For any future reader who needs the code:

```
Dim FoundMatch As Boolean
Try
    FoundMatch = Regex.IsMatch(SubjectString, "^(?:tru|fals)e$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
Catch ex As ArgumentException
    'Syntax error in the regular expression
End Try
```

Comment: Validation not firing with this expression because of ?i

Comment: @VigneshKumar Ha? Strange. Since that's the case I put the case-insensitivity in the code.

Comment: @vignesh With RegexOptions.IgnoreCase instead of (?i)

Answer (score 4):

Use `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` option and use the below regex:

```
^(true|false)$
```

or use ignore case modifer `?i`

Like this:

```
^(?i:true|false)$
```

Another option would be to convert the string to lower case and just use `^(true|false)$`

Comment: Validation not firing with this expression because of `?i `

Answer (score 2):

Another approach for words `True` or `False`:

```
If Boolean.TryParse(yourString, New Boolean) = true Then
    'ok
else
    'not ok
End If
```

If you want convert text to boolean variable and use it later:

```
Dim value As Boolean
If Boolean.TryParse(yourString, value) = true Then
    'Use value
else
    'Handle a wrong text situation
End If
```

`Boolean.TryParse` ignore case. `trUe` or `TRUE` parsed ok